# Calling an overridden method in a derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, derived-class

Let's suppose we have 3 classes: Person, Student and Worker. Student and Worker both are derived from Person. I want to make an array of persons, which consists of randomly position Student and Worker instances. There is a method called show() overloaded in both Student and Worker and I want to call that function instead of the Person show() method. I know how to do by casting the Person object like (Student*) or (Worker*) how could I use that method in array? Below is some sample code;

class Person:

```
Person::Person() {    
    this->name = new std::string("Gabi");
    this->age = 12;
}

void Person::show() {   
    std::cout << "Hi my name is " << *(this->name) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "and I am " << this->age << " years old" << std::endl;
}
```

class Student:

```
Student::Student() { 
    this->school = new std::string("ghica");
}

void Student::show() {

    Person::show();
    std::cout << "My school is " << *(this->school) << std::endl;
}
```

class Worker:

```
Worker::Worker() {
    this->workplace = new std::string("google");
}

void Worker::show() { 
    Person::show();
    std::cout << "My workplace is " << *(this->workplace) << std::endl;
}
```

If I call the show() method this way:

```
Person * myperson = new Student("Andrei", 29, "ghica");
myperson->show();
```

the school message will not appear, but if I do this:

```
Person * myperson = new Student("Andrei", 29, "ghica");
((Student*)myperson)->show();
```

it does. Any ideas?

Comment: is your `show` member function `virtual` ?

Comment: You should use a virtual function for `show`

Comment: Please post also the C++ headers or declarations.

Comment: @Angew Argh misspelled, yes that's right. Fixed thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overriding a method isn't sufficient to have it called via a pointer/reference to the base class. You need to make it virtual:

```
class Person {
public:
  virtual void show() { // Virtual function
      std::cout << "person show";
  }
};

class Worker : public Person {
public:    
  void show() {
      std::cout << "Worker show";
  }
};

int main() {

    Person obj;
    Worker obj2;

    Person* array[2];
    array[0] = &obj;
    array[1] = &obj2;


    array[0]->show(); // Person
    array[1]->show(); // Worker

   return 0;
}
```

<kbd>[Example](http://ideone.com/PAagVE)</kbd>

Answer (score 2):

Declare the `show` method in the `Person` class as **`virtual`**:

```
class Person
{
    ....
    virtual void show();
    ....
};
```

Also, even if unrelated to the question, it's often useless to place `this->` in front of each member variable use; in addition, I see you are declaring `name` and `school` as pointer to string: in most of cases this is unnecessary and wrong because you are giving up [value semantic](http://akrzemi1.wordpress.com/2012/02/03/value-semantics/).

Comment: how about return type ?